# Please help with this basic combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

**Statement**

20 Students in a class have to vote to elect a president. There are 3 candidates :
a) In how many ways can the votes be distributed?

b)In how many of these ways will Peter have the most votes?

**I tried:**
a) We can see that the votes are undistinguishable objects, this can be seen as a problem of combinations with repetition, where we have two delimiters and 20 balls to arrange. There are $22 \choose  20$ =231 ways to do this. I know this is right.

b) My reasoning: Peter needs at least 11 votes to win a majority. We set those aside and distribute the other 9 in $11 \choose  9$ =55 ways. But the right answer should be 73, according to my textbook. What is my problem? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Just to be clear is the student pool and the candidate pool the same? (i.e, 20 students and each of them are candidates as well)? It seems realistically everyone votes for themselves if so :p

Comment: My understanding from what I read is that there are 3 fixed candidates and they are students themselves @Vercingetorix

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect this- you wrote that there are 20 candidates and provided no number amongst the students.

Comment: @Vercingetorix you are right, I wrote it incorrectly, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) If there are $3$ candidates and $20$ voters, then this is a stars and bars problem. As you noted, $2$ delimiters (bars) and $20$ stars:

${22 \choose 20} = 231$

(b) isn't asking for a majority (which is what you're trying to  calculate) but merely a plurality. Ex: if candidate A gets $8$, $B$ gets $7$ and C gets $5$  then A still has the most votes even though they don't have a majority.

First, remove the possibilities where no one has the most number of votes,i.e, there's a tie; these look like:

$10, 10, 0$ and $9, 9, 2$ and $8, 8, 4$ and $7, 7, 6$

So that's $4 \times 3 = 12$ possibilities where there's no clear winner. Leaving us with $231 - 12 = 219$ possibilities where there's a clear plurality. By symmetry, Peter wins in $219/3 = 73$ of these.